# When nullable integer got null value not executing the command

Tags: vb.net, nullable

I have VB.Net code which value taking from db and if it is null do some job

```
While reader.Read
            tocken = reader.GetInt16("Tocken_No")
            If tocken.HasValue = False Then
                TxtPTocken.Text = 1
            Else
                TxtPTocken.Text = tocken + 1
            End If
        End While
```

Else statement working properly but first part not. tocken is nullable short. What I'm missing? Please help

Comment: You should turn on Option Strict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code doesn't make sense.  You're calling `GetInt16`, which means you're going to get an `Int16`.  Your `tocken` variable may be type `Nullable(Of Short)` but you're assigning a value to it so `HasValue` is ALWAYS going to be `True`.

Your issue there is that if your database field is NULL then your code is going to throw an exception.  Methods like `GetIn16` fail if there isn't a value of the expected type available.  It's up to you to check for NULL and handle that accordingly:

```
tocken = If(reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("Tocken_No")),
            CType(Nothing, Short?),
            reader.GetInt16("Tocken_No"))
```

Comment: My problem was by my select query reader didn't have any row to read. I add command to check hasrow outside row and now I am happy. Thanks for your help